# Observerable sequence of random numbers within a range

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, rxjs, rxjs5

How can i create an observable sequence of random numbers within a range using the [rxjs observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md)?

I can iterate over a range using [`range`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/range.md).

For example:

```
Observable.range(0, 20)
    .flatMap(data => getImage(data))
    .map(data => this.image = data);
```

However, i would like to have it continuously generate a random number for the sequence until i force it to stop. **Not** just iterate through the values until it is done.

NOTE: I am using [rxjs 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS). Which does not have a `while`.

Comment: how do you force it to stop?

Comment: @user3743222 I added the answer to your question inside my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate the random number within intervals of time. This is exactly what i needed.

```
let mySubscription: Subscription<number> = Observable.interval(3000)
    .map(data => generateRandomNumber(...))
    .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("complete")
    );
```

---

To stop the observer, simply unsubscribe from the subscription.

```
mySubscription.unsubscribe();
```

---

`generateRandomNumber()` is a method that just generates a random number for me. It is out of scope of the issue.

Comment: ah ok, I haven't got from the question that you wanted to generate the random every period of time. That's an important detail because with `range` you emit all the values sequentially (actually also synchronously) immediately one after the other, so you might not even get a chance to unsubscribe before all values are emitted.

Comment: @user3743222 Yeah, i may not have worded the question correctly. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) you could do something like this using [Observable.from](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/generators.md):
([Typescript support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript))

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pukilesowo/edit?js,console)

```
function* generator(min, max){
  while (true) {
    yield Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }
}

Rx.Observable.from(generator(0, 9000))
  .take(42)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```